# Remover div "Clone" em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma div que pode ser clonada em jquery, preciso que ao clicar em "Fechar div" remove a div clonada ao ser clicado...

Segue o código..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var linha = $(".engloba:first").clone();
    $("#mais").click(function() {
        $("#conteudo_engloba").append(linha.clone());
    });
 });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="button" name="" value="CLONAR" id="mais">
</form>

<div id="conteudo_engloba">
 <div class="engloba">
  <p>Fechar DIV</p>
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta no clique eliminar o ultimo elemento clonado. Acho que é isso que quer, acrescentei uma classe (`fechar`) ao `<p>Fechar DIV</p>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var linha = $(".engloba:first").clone();
    $("#mais").click(function() {
       $("#conteudo_engloba").append(linha.clone());
    });
    $("#conteudo_engloba").on('click', '.fechar', function() {
       $(this).parent().remove();
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="button" name="" value="CLONAR" id="mais">
</form>

<div id="conteudo_engloba">
 <div class="engloba">
  <p class="fechar">Fechar DIV</p>
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: é isso mesmo amigo, muito obrigado!!

Comment: De nada @Alh. Ainda bem que ajudei